# Are all engines fan blades made out of titanium?

Tags: engine, engine-design

I was wondering if all engine fan blades are really made out of titanium.

Comment: Of course not all of them. F119 and F135 are the two that does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many, but not all. Rolls-Royce has been working on carbon fibre fan blades for a long time, using the material as far back as 1968 on the [RR. Conway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolls-Royce_Conway). They planned to use carbon fibre (Hyfil) for the RB.211 too, but had to switch to titanium when they couldn't get the Hyfil blades to work reliably during bird ingestion tests.

The [GE90](https://www.geaviation.com/commercial/engines/ge90-engine) uses carbon fibre fan blades, with titanium leading edges.

Comment: Others: CFM LEAP and GE9X are composite, the PW1000G is aluminum.